# Macro to Move Columns Based on Header Criteria MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm starting a new position in 8 days and I'm quite new to visual basic.  I was able to job shadow a current employee and in 1 of the reports, the individual was sifting through 100 or so columns selecting 8 or so for report and copying and pasting into a new worksheet.

What I would like to accomplish is the following:

Create a Macro that looks at worksheet 2, in which I would have the 8 column headers for the report, looks at worksheet 1 (primary sheet) and finds the 8 columns and moves the data (not headers) over to worksheet 2.  This would help speed up the report, there is other things I would like it to be able to do, but this would serve as a great starting point.

I.E.: Sheet 2 would have: Contractor Name, Manager Name, Project Description, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As basic as possible.

```vb
1 |Sub copycolumns()
2 |Dim i As Integer, searchedcolumn As Integer, searchheader As Object
3 |
4 |For i = 1 To 8
5 |
6 |   set searchheader = Sheets(2).Cells(1, i)
7 |
8 |   searchedcolumn = 0
9 |   On Error Resume Next
10|   searchedcolumn = Sheets(1).Rows(1).Find(what:=searchheader.value, lookat:=xlWhole).Column
11|   On Error GoTo 0
12|
13|   If searchedcolumn <> 0 Then
14|      Sheets(1).Columns(searchedcolumn).Copy Destination:=searchheader
15|   End If
16|    
17|Next i
18|
19|End Sub
```

- Line 4: Uses a FOR-Loop which steps a variable from 1 to 8.
  The variable `i` stands for the current column in sheet 2
- Line 6: Here we save the current header (a single cell) as an object. This object will be reused in line 10 and 14
- Line 8: You have to reset the search variable `searchedcolumn` before you do a new search. If you don't and the search will fail (not present in sheet 1), the variable still holds the old value.
- Line 10: The `find` method is the key part of the whole macro. It took the string of your current column from sheet 2 and searches for it in the first row of sheet 1. If there is a positive search hit, the corresponding column number is stored in the variable `searchedcolumn`
- Line 9 and 11: This starts and stops the error handler. This way if an error occurs in line 10 you won't get an internal VBA error message. Instead the code will go on.
- Line 13: Test if the find method has found something and the value has changed from zero to a valid column number.
- Line 14: If yes, copy the whole column from sheet 1 to the corresponding column in sheet 2

---

**Note:** The code can be shortened even more. But than it would be more complicated to explain everything.

Of course you have to manually delete the index number at the beginning of every line.

Comment: Nixda - Thank you so much for your help!!! You provided a very nice explanation for everything.  I can't wait to learn more of this stuff =)